# Conditional Formatting reset on group change

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report that shows a comparison of MPG a certain vehicle got from last year and this year. I want to highlight the current year's MPG in relation to whether it is greater or less than the previous year. If MPG has improved in the current year, I want the number to show green, if it is less than previous year, I want it to show red. I have two formulas that calculate the MPG, one for each year. In the Section Expert, I go to font and enter this in the font forumla:
    if{@Current Qtr MPG}>={@Previous Qtr MPG} then crGreen else 
    crRed

However, the highlight isn't quite right. The result is that ALL the current year values have been turned green, even if they are less than the previous year and only 0 values have turned red. I suspect this has something to do with needing to reset the formatting formula at each group level, but I'm unclear on how that's done.

This may seem similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36210008/highlight-value-if-greater-or-less-than-previous-years-value) other post of mine, but it is different. In the first post, both values I wanted to compare were from the same field on different rows. This post is a simpler questions because I'm attempting to highlight one field based on how it compares to another separate field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlight value if greater or less than previous year's value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36210008/highlight-value-if-greater-or-less-than-previous-years-value)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The first post is asking how to get the highlight to work when both values are from the same field/formula. This one has the values coming from different formulas to simplify the highlight.

Comment: My apology. Can you edit the above post and show the content of the two formulas you are comparing?